# Variable printing in python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to declare a variable and print its value.

This is my code:

```
#!C:\Python32\python.exe
import sys
import os
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
a = 5
print(a)-------------------------> My doubt is in this line
```

But one of my friends writes that line as `print a`. In his Python, it is printing that value, but in my case it is showing as "Invalid Syntax". Why is this happening?

Comment: read [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're in Python 3, [`print` is a function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), so you call it as: `print(a)`. In Python 2 (what your friend is using), you can leave off the parenthesis, and call it as just: `print a`, but *this won't work in the future*, so **your way is correct**.

Also, your version (`print(a)`) will work on both Python 3 and Python 2, since extra parenthesis are ignored as long as they match. I recommend always writing it in Python 3 style, since it works in both. You can make this explicit and required by using the (somewhat magical) [`__future__` module](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Having `print` as a function causes some other differences, since in Python 3, you can set a variable to point to `print`, or pass it as an argument to a function:

```
a = print
a('magic') # prints 'magic'

def add_and_call(func, num):
    num += 1
    func(num)

add_and_call(print, 1) # prints 2
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, `print` isn't a function, but a keyword. The parentheses therefore don't matter and `print 'foo'` works along with `print('foo')`.

Python 3 made `print` into a function, which *has* to be called with parameters: `print('foo')`. Calling it as `print 'foo'` will not work anymore.

Since you're getting errors when using `print` as a keyword, you're using Python 3. You have to use `print` as a function, just like you did. Your friend is using Python 2, which works both ways.

Python 3 and Python 2 are similar, but there are a few major differences that you should read about if you're planning on collaborating with someone who uses a different version of Python: http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html